# TensorFlow: Why does I get different result even though I run this code twice at same place without updata any parameters？

Tags: tensorflow

I have built a CNN model in mnist_inference.py, and I want to compute the accuracy every 100 steps. But I found it dosen't work right. After long time debugging, I found the result was changing when I computed the value of y. At first, I considered it becouse of the parameters was auto-update when I computed y. But no! I found the parameters didn't change. 
So how do I compute the accuracy of my model?
This is my code:[mycode](https://github.com/zhangqinghao0811/mycode/blob/master/mnist_train.py)

Comment: I tried to solve this by myself, but I'm stuck in this problem. Does anyone could tell me how to solve this?
Thanks in advance!ヾ(*´—`*)ﾉ

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This line of your code

```py
y = mnist_inference.inference(x, True, regularizer)
```

Creates model with dropouts:

```py
def inference(input_tensor, train, regularizer):

    # code fragment

    with tf.variable_scope('layer5-fc1'):
        fc1_weights = tf.get_variable("weight", [nodes, FC_SIZE],
                                      initializer = tf.truncated_normal_initializer(stddev = 0.1))

        if regularizer != None:
            tf.add_to_collection('losses', regularizer(fc1_weights))
        fc1_biases = tf.get_variable('bias', [FC_SIZE], initializer = tf.constant_initializer(0.1))
        fc1 = tf.nn.relu(tf.matmul(reshaped, fc1_weights)+fc1_biases)

        # enables dropout!
        if train:
            fc1 = tf.nn.dropout(fc1, 0.5)
```

So you have dropouts enabled and that results in randomness you observe.

You need to disable dropout when computing accuracy. Higher level [`tf.layers.dropout`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/layers/dropout) has corresponding parameter (that can be a tensor).

Comment: When I see dropouts, I understand. Thanks a lot! （づ￣3￣）づ╭❤～

Comment: I only check my 'train' part code, and completely forget dorpouts. Thanks again!

Comment: I earned 15 reputation to upvote you to express my appreciation ^_^

Comment: My pleasure. This is what I should do.